# bootstrap.properties not working with @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I'm struggling with some spring-cloud-stuff regarding automated testing and integrated tomcat-server being configured to use some random port.

First I [opened a bug on the spring-boot project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11295), because I was thinking they are responsible for taking action, but it got refused with a pointer to some Gitter-channel, but it might be a good place here too.

My setup contains a lib, where I have prepared a Feign-client like this:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "some-service-name", url = "${someServiceName.rest.url}")
public interface SomeServiceRESTDAO {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dummy", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean dummy();

}
```

The idea is to have some re-usable Feign-client, but without the requirement of having some registry lying around, and having a default value. This is inside the `bootstrap.properties`:

```
someServiceName.rest.url=http://localhost:${server.port}/
```

This is my test-class, but not working as expected, because I can't get spring-boot testing working with my feign-client:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainClass.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    // this was some idea to set random port
    "server.port=${random.int[1024,65536]}"
    // this was some idea, but does not propagate
//    "server.port=${local.server.port}"
})
public class MainClassTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int localPort;

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int serverPort;

    @Value("${someServiceName.rest.url}")
    private String clientUrl;

    @Test
    public void dummyTest() {
        System.out.println("LocalPort: " + localPort);
        System.out.println("ServerPort: " + serverPort);
        System.out.println("ClientUrl: " + clientUrl);
        assertTrue(localPort == serverPort);
    }
}
```

The full code can be gathered from my [github-project](https://github.com/FibreFoX/spring-boot-with-bootstrap-and-feign-testing-bug)

Any suggestions?

Comment: try bootstrap.yml instead. It's the same but  we never know.

Comment: @georgesvan thats not true, it works with the properties-file, but ${server.port} resolves to "0" instead of the real server-port. Please review the project I referenced here (I didn't wanted to pollute all the code into this question, main points are here I think)